# How to prevent the user from entering more than one break in textarea using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

How can I prevent the user from inserting more than one line break in a row into a text field?
I prefer a solution using jQuery.

UPDATE 1:

I have inserted anadeo's code into my code which looks like the following. Unfortunately it doesn't work - it still allows more than one line break in a row in the textarea #posttext. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks :)

```
//Post something
$('#postDiv').on('keydown', '#posttext', function(e) {
if (e.which==13 && !e.shiftKey && $('#posttext').val()!=' Post something...') {

    var last = false;

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) {
        if (last) { e.preventDefault(); }
        last=true;
    }else{
        last=false;
    }

    //If not currently loading and enough text typed in, submit
    if($('#imageFeedback').html()!=' | Loading...' && $('#posttext').val().length>15){

        //Say that it is loading
        $('#imageFeedback').css('color','black').css('font-weight','normal').html(' | Loading...');

        //Call function to post
        post($(this));
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Comment: Nope, to be honest I have no idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(textarea).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13 && this.value.match(/\n/g)) e.preventDefault();
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/RF9QE/1/)

```
...more than one line break in a row
```

Are you thinking of avoiding more than one line break in a row (one after another), like so:

```
var last = false;

$(textarea).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) {
        if (last) { e.preventDefault(); }
        last=true;
    }else{
        last=false;
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/RF9QE/2/)

**EDIT:**

Firstly, `on()` is only supported in jQuery 1.7+, so make sure you are using a newer version of the library.

You are also using the delegated version of `on()`, and that should'nt be a problem, but it assumes that your textarea is inserted into the DOM at a later time, and not present from the start, ie. it's dynamically inserted with JS etc.

The rest seems ok, but the `last` variable will have to be placed outside the keydown function to work properly, and the var `code` should be at the top, doing the check for the enter key only once, as the second check is not really necessary.
The `code` variable is really optional, as jQuery is supposed to normalize `e.which`, but doing a check to see if `keycode` or `which` is supported seems like a good idea to ensure cross browser compatibility.

The check for the `#posttext` value will only work once, as soon as a linebreak is entered the value is no longer  `Post something...`, and the "limit linebreaks" function will be enabled?

All in all I think this should work, try it and see ?

```
var last = false;

$('#postDiv').on('keydown', '#posttext', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code==13 && !e.shiftKey && $('#posttext').val()!=' Post something...') {
        if (last) { e.preventDefault(); }
        last=true;
    }else{
        last=false;
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cjc2W/)

Also, It would probably be a good idea to use a less common variable name instead of `last`, something like `MyLastTyped`, `PostTextLast` etc. that is less likely to be confused with a function or variable with the name `last` in some other place or plugin etc.

Comment: Like to see people using `.on()`

Comment: @adeneo In fiddle it works and that is exactly what I need. Please see question edit, I have included it in my code but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dennis - Updated my answer as it was a little to much for a comment, see if that's working for you now, if not I'll have a look at it again !

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this:

**NEW AND IMPROVED** (can define how many newlines allowed)

http://jsfiddle.net/cEzUx/6/

```
<textarea id="my" rows="5"></textarea>
<div id="out"> </div>

maxBreaks = 1;

$("#my").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {    
        if(countBreaks($("#my").val()) == maxBreaks) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

function countBreaks(str) {
  var num = 0;        
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) === '\n') { num++; }
  }
  return num;
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myTarea").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
       if($(this).val().match(/\n/)) e.preventDefault();
    }
});

<textarea id="myTarea" rows="5"></textarea>
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cEzUx/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The key to the solution is to prevent the default behavior of inserting the carriage return `\n`, once you detect that there is at least one `\n` character on the page.

In the `event` object passed into the keypress handler, use the "which" method to check for the enter key "keypress" event, which is represented by the number 13. If that key is pressed, check the entire contents of the textarea for a carriage return, which again is represented by the escape sequence `\n`. If the length of the collection of `\n` characters is greater than 0, then invoke `event.preventDefault()`, which prevents the enter key from being added to the textarea's value property:

```
$('#wmd-input').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13 && $('#wmd-input').val().match(/\n/g).length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```